# More elegant way to avoid this hacky implementation of single line reduce for grouping a collection?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In [my evolved answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54337537/how-to-create-multiple-lists-from-one-list-according-to-matching-substrings/54337725#54337725), I came up with a way to do a single line (well, single expression) `reduce` to create the results of `groupby` as defined by many other languages (Kotlin, ObjC, Swift, Smalltalk, at least).

My initial attempt looked like:

```
def keyFunc(value):
    return derivative_of_value

grouped = reduce(
    lambda accum, each: accum[keyFunc(each)].append(each),
    allValues,
    defaultdict(list))
```

As stated in my Aside/Tangent there, the problem is the lambda. A lambda is limited to a single expression. And for it to work in reduce, it must return a modified version of the accumulated argument.

So I came up with the following hack, using a tuple to move the dict reference from reduction to reduction, but also force the (ignored) side effect of updating the same dict:

```
from functools import reduce
grouped = reduce(
    lambda accum, each: (accum[0], accum[0][keyFunc(each)].append(each)),
    allValues,
    (defaultdict(list), None))[0]
```

*The Question* is... is there a better way? **Given** the constraint that I want to try and still use a single expression reduce without a bunch of helper functions.

*(I recognize that sometimes the code is telling you something, but I'm interested in this case for the academic side of things)*

Comment: honestly, it's not even readable

Comment: That is indeed hacky and ugly :)   [python-split](https://bitbucket.org/astanin/python-split/src/default/README) offers a souped-up `groupby` which doesn't require a sorted input for the basic use-case.

Comment: This is a terribe one-liner. You are using a side-effect inside your `reduce`, which is a terrible misuse of the functional construct, IMO. Just use a for-loop with the defaultdict. That is the idiomatic way. If you want to do it in a single line, define a function and call that function in a single line. Don't abuse functional constructs.

Comment: aren't we grumpy today? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted this to the python mailing list and received two solutions that were the basic same trick, but were more elegant refinements:

```
grouped = reduce(
    lambda groups, each: groups[keyFunc(each)].append(each) or groups,
    allValues,
    defaultdict(list))
```

This uses an `or` to skip over the `None` return from the part that does the actual work. Yay for falsey.

```
grouped = reduce(
    lambda groups, each: (groups[keyFunc(each)].append(each), groups)[1],
    allValues,
    defaultdict(list))
```

This second one still uses the tuple, but isolates just to the point that its needed so it doesn't leak over the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to do this with reduce or even defaultdict. But there are one-line solutions using list/dict comprehension. For example, given

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> def func1(a):
...     return str(a)
>>> b = list(range(10)) + list(range(5))
>>> b
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

the following is a one-line solution with dict:

```
>>> {x: [y for y in b if func1(y) == x] for x in set([func1(z) for z in b])}
{'4': [4, 4], '5': [5], '2': [2, 2], '8': [8], '9': [9], '7': [7], '0': [0, 0], '3': [3, 3], '1': [1, 1], '6': [6]}
```

---

The solutions below get the job done, but are bad (as pointed out by @juanpa.arrivillaga in the comments) because you are creating a potentially very large list and then throw it away immediately. See [Is it Pythonic to use list comprehensions for just side effects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects)

More one-line solutions (2-lines actually if you count the defaultdict(list) initialization line) using list comprehension.

For example, with defaultdict

```
>>> a = defaultdict(list)
>>> [a[func1(x)].append(x) for x in b]
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
>>> a
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'0': [0, 0], '1': [1, 1], '2': [2, 2], '3': [3, 3], '4': [4, 4], '5': [5], '6': [6], '7': [7], '8': [8], '9': [9]})
```

Or with normal dict

```
>>> c = {}
>>> [c[func1(x)].append(x) if c.get(func1(x)) else c.update({func1(x):[x]}) for x in b]
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
>>> c
{'0': [0, 0], '1': [1, 1], '2': [2, 2], '3': [3, 3], '4': [4, 4], '5': [5], '6': [6], '7': [7], '8': [8], '9': [9]}
```

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects)[juanpa.arrivillaga]

Comment: Interesting fu. These don't really use reduce(), one of the hoped for advantages in my original approach was that keyFunc() was called as little as possible.

Comment: The interesting technique of using comprehension to do lots of work on one line is clever though. I wasn't thrilled with the "create a list/dictionary" just to throw it away side effect though. But it inspired me to do this one:

Comment: `any(a[func1(x)].append(x) for x in b)`

Comment: That’s smart! It will call keyFunc once per x.

Comment: don't use side-effects inside a list-comprehension